# Change data source with spin button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dashboard that connects to a combo box (red circle). This connects to a list of table names, I then have a macro that updates the source data to what is selected in the combo box.

I want to do the same but with a spin button (blue circle) I can't see an option to change the input range so my macro doesn't work.

Does anyone know some way I can use a spin button to change the data source? Given the list of tables is already in the sheet, maybe I could some how use VBA to loop through these?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Scott

---

The code to change the data source is as below, it simply refers to .list as the combo box has the ability for this list to be specified, this single column range contains the table names [DASHBOARD!$Q$58:$Q$138]

The spin button doesn't look to have the ability to specify the range in the same way.

```
Sub ChangeDataSource()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        .List(.Value)
    End With
```

[image]

---

UPDATE 1

Code from @FaneDuru looks like it works! but that does create some new problems

1. I can't get the graph axis update macro to work no matter where I put it, this just formats the axis to the use able range. Any ideas why this wouldn't be triggering?
2. Is it possible at the end of the loop to reset to the first line rather then stopping
3. I probably need to export the table name being used to cell "U6" so people can see what stock they are looking at. Any idea how to do this inside or outside of VBA?

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

   Dim shDSh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, spVal As Long, i As Long
   
    Set shDSh = Worksheets("DASHBOARD")
    arr = shDSh.Range("Q58:Q138").Value
    spVal = Me.SpinButton1.Value
    
    If spVal >= 1 And spVal <= UBound(arr, 1) Then
    '   MsgBox arr(spVal, 1)
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotTableWizard _
                  SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=arr(spVal, 1)
                  
    'Call ADJUST_Click
                  
    Else
        MsgBox "Spin button value """ & spVal & """ exceedes the names range area"
    End If
    
    'call ADJUST_Click
    
End Sub
```

---

UPDATE 2 - this is the code the resets all the chart min/max values. I was trying to call this after the above loop, but have no idea why that wouldn't work.

```
Sub AdjustChart()

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim srs As Series
Dim FirstTime  As Boolean
Dim MaxNumber As Double
Dim MinNumber As Double
Dim MaxChartNumber As Double
Dim MinChartNumber As Double
Dim Padding As Double

Padding = 0.01
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
      FirstTime = True
      For Each srs In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
          MaxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(srs.Values)
            If FirstTime = True Then
              MaxChartNumber = MaxNumber
            ElseIf MaxNumber > MaxChartNumber Then
              MaxChartNumber = MaxNumber
            End If
          MinNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(srs.Values)
            If FirstTime = True Then
              MinChartNumber = MinNumber
            ElseIf MinNumber < MinChartNumber Or MinChartNumber = 0 Then
              MinChartNumber = MinNumber
            End If
      FirstTime = False
      Next srs
      cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber * (1 - Padding)
      cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxChartNumber * (1 + Padding)
Next cht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

UPDATE 3 - Tried this on the spin button.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

arr = Range("Q58:Q138").Value
spVal = Me.SpinButton1.Value

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFor
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=arr(spVal, 1)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the code you tried? In principle, you must build an array keeping the table names and a value to match the spin to each other. Then, you can follow the logic of your existing code, I think...

Comment: I have added the code above, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
   Dim arr As Variant, spVal As Long, El As Variant
    arr = Split("Name1|1,Name2|2,Name3|3,Name4|4", ",")
    
    spVal = Me.SpinButton1.Value
    For Each El In arr
       If Split(El, "|")(1) = spVal Then MsgBox Split(El, "|")(0): Exit Sub
    Next
End Sub
```

Edited: The variant which collect the necessary array from a range ("Q58:Q138"). Try it, please and confirm that it does what (I understood) you need:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
   Dim shDSh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, spVal As Long, i As Long
   
    Set shDSh = Worksheets("DASHBOARD")
    arr = shDSh.Range("Q58:Q138").Value
    
    spVal = Me.SpinButton1.Value
    If spVal >= 1 And spVal <= UBound(arr, 1) Then
        'MsgBox arr(spVal, 1)
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotTableWizard _
                  SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=arr(spVal, 1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Spin button value """ & spVal & """ exceedes the names range area"
    End If
End Sub
```

I couldn't test it, not having such a pivot table, but it should work, I think. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Only down side is there is 100 names, and those change quite frequently so I can't really code them in. I'll post the code in the morning.

Comment: @Scottyp: If you have the names in discussion somewhere in a sheet and the order of using them respects a rule, I would be able to automatically extract them. Otherwise, how would you imagine that the code can "understand" what Name to be used of a specific SpinButton value? Without seeing your code it is impossible to imagine something else...

Comment: @Scottyp: Edited my answer and added another version specific to your case. Please, confirm that it does what you need it to do.

Comment: Does this line `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotTableWizard _
                  SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=arr(spVal, 1)` do what your previous list box value did?

Comment: @Scottyp: Some feedback would be appreciated. It would be, at least, polite to say something...

Comment: Hey man, I'm in a different time zone so I may take awhile sorry (GMT +10 so almost midnight) I definitely appreciate your help! 

The code in the comment immediately above comes up with error 438 - object doesnt support this method. 

```
Private Sub ChangeDataSource()
arr = Range("Q58:Q138").Value
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFor
      ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=arr(spVal, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Scottyp: You made me laugh... What you tried does not make any sense. You should test in the Spin button code... Only there it make sense, if `spVal` has a value. It is late now, and I will not bother you, anymore. But try please to test it in the code I posted... Does it behave like selecting a value in combo box and changing the pivot table according to the chosen name?

Comment: I tried it in the spin button first, as per the code above in edit 3, then tried in the combo box as you mentioned list box, so through you might have meant put it in the combo box